# Vertex position in feynmf diagram

Tags: diagrams, feynmf

I was trying to draw the following diagram, but the square of fermions it's too small and I want to make it bigger, but I don't know how

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{dm20}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(200,100)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}
    \fmf{dashes}{i1,t1}
    \fmf{dashes}{t2,i2}
    \fmf{phantom,tension = 1}{t1,t4}
    \fmf{phantom,tension = 1}{t2,t3}
    \fmf{dashes}{t4,o1}
    \fmf{dashes}{o2,t3}
    \fmf{fermion}{t1,t2,t3,t4,t1}
   \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `\setlength{\unitlength}{0.08cm}` into your code. Thus the square is more large than before.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{dm20}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.08cm}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(200,100)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}
    \fmf{dashes}{i1,t1}
    \fmf{dashes}{t2,i2}
    \fmf{dashes}{t4,o1}
    \fmf{phantom,tension = 1}{t1,t4}
    \fmf{phantom,tension = 1}{t2,t3}
    \fmf{dashes}{o2,t3}
    \fmf{fermion}{t1,t2,t3,t4,t1}
   \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works for me, thank you. @Sebastiano

Comment: @Davizon -- it's nice to see polite "thank you" comments, but the usual way that this site works is that you upvote the answer as well...

Comment: @Thruston No problem fot the upvote. Peraphs the user have 31 as reputation and he can not give a me a vote. :-)